# Hash a password field outside of the User model - Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to have a user register, and then log in.  Once they are logged in they specify their WiFi name, followed by a wifi password, and their choice of a VPN.  The problem I am having is hashing the wifi_password field upon saving it to the database.  I am trying to hash the password within the edit function in views.py. I have posted the entirety of my models, forms, and views.  The code is still sloppy, and will need some cleaning up when I can achieve functionality.  Thanks.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings

vpn_choices = [
                ('openvpn', 'Open VPN'),
                ('pia', 'Private Internet Access'),
                ('expressvpn', 'Express VPN'),
                ]
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                on_delete = models.CASCADE,
                                null = True)
    wifi = models.CharField(max_length = 128)
    wifi_password = models.CharField(max_length = 128)
    vpn_choice = models.CharField(max_length = 20, choices = vpn_choices)




    def __str__(self):
        return f'self.user.username {self.user.username}'
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, AbstractUser
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from server.models import Profile
from django.forms import ModelForm

vpn_choices = [
                ('openvpn', 'Open VPN'),
                ('pia', 'Private Internet Access'),
                ('expressvpn', 'Express VPN'),
                ]


class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length = 126)
    password = forms.CharField(max_length = 126, widget = forms.PasswordInput)


class UserRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(label = 'Password',
                                widget = forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label = 'Repeat Password',
                                widget = forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username',)

    def clean_password2(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        if cd['password'] != cd['password2']:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords don\'t match.')
        return cd['password2']


class ProfileEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('wifi', 'wifi_password', 'vpn_choice')
        labels = {
        'wifi': ('WiFi'),
        'wifi_password': ('WiFi Password'),
        'vpn_choice': ('VPN Choice'),
        }
        widgets = {
        'wifi_password': forms.PasswordInput
        }
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import LoginForm, UserRegistrationForm, ProfileEditForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from server.models import Profile
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password


def user_login(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            user = authenticate(request,
                                username = cd['username'],
                                password = cd['password'])
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return HttpResponse('Authenticated '\
                                        'successfully')
                else:
                    return HttpResponse('Disabled account')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid Login')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            # Create a new user object but avoid saving it yet
            new_user = user_form.save(commit = False)
            # Set the chosen password
            new_user.set_password(
                user_form.cleaned_data['password'])
            # Save the User object
            new_user.save()
            # Create the user profile
            Profile.objects.create(user = new_user)
            return render(request,
                            'register_done.html',
                            {'new_user': new_user})
    else:
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm()
    return render(request,
                    'register.html',
                    {'user_form': user_form})

@login_required
def user_logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))

@login_required
def edit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        profile_form = ProfileEditForm(instance = request.user.profile,
                                        data = request.POST)
        if profile_form.is_valid():
            settings = profile_form.save(commit = False)
            password = make_password('wifi_password')
            settings.save()
    else:
        profile_form = ProfileEditForm()
    return render(request, 'edit.html',
                    {'profile_form': profile_form})
```

Comment: You can override the `save` of `ProfileEditForm` to hash the password there. Or add `settings.wifi_password = make_password(settings.wifi_password)`

Comment: Thank you so much!  This worked exactly as needed after I continuously failed for a week.

Answer (score 1):

But if you will hash the password yourself, you will need to override `authenticate` as well as the Django won't be able to regenerate the hash to find the user record